# Is it possible to recover ArcGIS Online tiles of a zone, then reproject and republish them in a Map Service?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, map-service, arcgis-online

I'd like to use ArcGIS Online basemaps but not is the Web Mercator projection. Because of that I want to know if it's possible to reproject and republish them in a Map Service.

Comment: What's the client api you use?

Comment: I'm using the Flex API. But I have an ArcInfo licence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No. If you are using on ArcGIS Desktop, all Tiled MapService can project to the other projection. However, all Web Mappings API such as Flex, javascript and Silverlight, project Tiled MapService is not supporting. This means, your map's spatialreference need to be same as the Tiled Map Service's spatialreference.And also, you cannot republish other MapService as your own MapService.
By the way, most web services are using Web Mercator. So, if there aren't a big problem, you would better to use Web Mercator.

Comment: "you cannot republish other MapService as your own MapService" means that it's illegal (ESRI doesn't give authorization for that) or it's technically impossible?

Comment: @yo_haha I mean technically impossible. The layer type of MapServerLayer is not supporting publish. But also I guess there are including license problem.

Comment: "The layer type of MapServerLayer is not supporting publish"
I don't see exacltly what you mean. Could you please give me a link to understand better?

Comment: @yo_haha oh, sorry for bad english. Please read following information. "ArcGIS Server layers" and "Tiled map service layers" are not supporting at MapServices. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq0000001m000000